# Imported KML Feature won't display in Earth Engine map

Tags: kml, features, google-earth-engine

I have converted a shapefile polygon to a KML file using QGIS, and now am trying to import it to a Google Earth Engine feature table to clip some NDVI difference analysis I'm conducting, but I can't get the polygon to display in the GEE map.

The link to the KML polygon is here: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1b_lTfxp3ne0PBN_BRG7MgbWLG0dlyjMtWjWF0EEf

And the code I'm using to try to display it is here:

```js
// display Leyte province, Philippines 
// data from: http://www.philgis.org/freegisdata.htm

var leyte = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1b_lTfxp3ne0PBN_BRG7MgbWLG0dlyjMtWjWF0EEf');

Map.addLayer(leyte, {'color':'00FF00'});
Map.setCenter(124.65087, 11.0544296, 8);
```

I think there might be an issue with the geocoding that's keeping it from displaying, but can't identify the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `print(leyte);` and open the Console, you'll see the FeatureCollection is trying to draw the polygon with `geo_column: ISO`, which is clearly not your KML geometry column from the Fusion table. I was able to display the polygon instead just by specifying the correct geometry column, which in this case is called `geometry`:

```js
var leyte = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1b_lTfxp3ne0PBN_BRG7MgbWLG0dlyjMtWjWF0EEf', 'geometry');
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was something simple but that I was just missing. Cheers.