# Points from QGIS to GEE

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine

Let me preface by saying I'm a beginner but have read a lot and can't find what I need. I have a set of coordinates from QGIS that I want to upload to Google Earth Engine and I can get as far as importing the table but none of the scripts I've found seem to be working to add them to my map. What am I missing? I just need the points to display or to figure out how to get my dNBR layers from GEE to QGIS.

Comment: Please edit your post so it contains what you tried.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the geometry property name? [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192485/imported-kml-feature-wont-display-in-earth-engine-map?rq=1)

Comment: To be honest I have tried copying, pasting, and modifying so many different scripts I just cleared it all out so all I have is the dNBR script and the table imported as an asset. I'm sure I'm missing a step (like specifying the geometry maybe) but at this point I've just confused myself more than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (Confirm upload) Can you confirm that your points are present as an asset. In the [Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/) click the "Assets" tab in the left panel. Do any of the assets with a table icon match the name you provided to the upload dialog? If you don't see it, please refer to the [Importing section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing) of the Developer Guide.
2. (Import to script) If your asset is present, follow the [Importing assets to your script section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/asset_manager#importing-assets-to-your-script) of the Developer Guide.
3. (Add to Map) See the [Adding data to the map section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/getstarted#adding-data-to-the-map) of the Developer Guide.

```js
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/<myUserName>/<myCoordinates>');
Map.centerObject(fc);
Map.addLayer(fc, {color: 'red'}, 'My Coordinates');
```

4. (Still don't see points?) Maybe the geometry is `null`. Check by printing the coordinates:

```js
print(fc.geometry().coordinates())
```

A list of lists will be printed to the console. If the sublists are empty, the features have no geometry. Something may have gone wrong in exporting from QGIS and/or uploading to EE. Start by checking the export from QGIS - if it looks okay, try re-uploading to EE.

When uploading a CSV file, be sure to set as many "Advanced options" as you can to control the upload:

[image]

Comment: I confirmed the table as an asset, do these properties look correct?
type: FeatureCollection
id: users/sarahbethdeaton/randomPoints
version: 1575928885817492
columns: Object (5 properties)
id: Integer
X: Float
Y: Float
fid: Integer
system:index: String
properties: Object (1 property)
system:asset_size: 9515

Still no points so I'm thinking it is the geometry since I don't know how to set that. I also don't know how to get the copy of my script in the shaded boxes.

Comment: What gets printed to the console when you run this in the EE script editor - there should be lists of coordinates: `print(ee.FeatureCollection('users/sarahbethdeaton/randomPoints').first().geometry().coordinates())`

Comment: Just empty brackets: [ ]

Comment: Okay, so the features have no geometry. Can you check to make sure the file you are uploading to EE has geometry. Try to load it into QGIS or ArcMap if it is a shapefile. Or maybe is it a CSV file?

Comment: It is a csv file. Column headers are X, Y, fid, and id.

Comment: Could you paste an example of one row here?

Comment: -121.5355108 39.72599173 1 0

Comment: That all looks fine, except that maybe this is space of tab delimited data, and the EE upload defaults to comma. When you uploaded to EE, did you set all of the "Advanced options" that you could? I edited my answer above to include the upload dialog - if you did not, make sure to set x and y col names, crs, and csv delimiter. The default entries are provided. If your lon and lat columns are named x and y respectively, that could explain the lack of geometry.

Comment: I opened the csv in Notepad to double check the delimiter was a comma and it is. I also re-uploaded the table to make sure I filled everything in. I am now getting this error in the console: Cannot read property "coordinates" of null.

Comment: It sounds like it thinks you have a primary geometry column. In your csv file, try naming the x column as longitude and the y column as latitude. Be sure to read the last paragraph of this section closely: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing#upload-a-csv-file

Comment: It worked! I have read that paragraph probably 10 times and just had it mixed it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Woohoo I'm glad you got it working! I write documentation for the EE Developer Guide. Let me know if you have any suggestions for making this section more clear and I'll update the doc.